# It takes a long time before the data is updated using graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We want to use graph to collect the views, likes and comment for news in SharePoint Online. However, since a couple of days it takes a long time before for instance the likecount gets updated. The footer of the page immediately shows the correct number of likes but using graph (explorer) it takes hours.
The graph call appears to be correct because it worked up unto a couple of days before.
If we use the REST API, the data is updated instantly.

The call we use is: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listId}/items/{listItemId}

Comment: Graph Explorer uses the REST API. So that we understand correctly, a property called likecount isn't updated as frequently as it had prior, correct?

Comment: @Michael this is correct. When doing a call directly to the REST API we get the new Like & Comment count, but when doing this call to Graph it returns an old resultset. It will take a really long time to update or not update at all in some cases. We can force an update by republishing the page, the counts are then correct again.
We can provide a fiddler trace if wanted.

Comment: This is a naive question, are you using the Microsoft Graph REST API or a deemphasized SharePoint Online REST API (I don't know if it exists)? It sounds like when you use the Graph REST API the results can be based on an older state and it takes some time until the results reflect the updated state, but if you use a SharePoint REST API, the results are current, am I correct?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Let me clarify our problem some more.
We are using the Graph API for all our calls, however starting 2 weeks ago this specific call is no longer returning the expected results on several tenants. After a tip on a different support forum we checked the data using the V2 SharePoint API (https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/) and noticed the like and comment count was updated there after a minute. We understand it can take some time to update the count , but we now have items which haven’t had their state updated for over 2 weeks. That looks like a bug.

Comment: @MichaelMainer  Adding a comment from Judith Steijne who doesn't have rep to comment.  ->
This is correct. When doing a call directly to the REST api we get the new Like & Comment count, but when doing this call to Graph it returns an old resultset. It will take a really long time to update or not update at all in some cases. We can force an update by republishing the page, the counts are then correct again.
We can provider a fiddler trace if wanted.